# Building Camera App, it cannot take pictures. Returns with "D/[App Name]: failed to create directory"

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on an app where I can take pictures. I am mostly using this as a tutorial: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera#capture-picture 
It should be noted I do not plan to have it record videos.

Anyway, every time I click the button to take the picture, there is some lag and nothing happens.  The Logcat says "D/[App name]: failed to create directory".  Yes, I did search for the term, but could not find a solution that really helped me.

The weirdest part is if I were to click the capture button again, the app crashes with the following message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.assessment, PID: 13633
    java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
        at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
        at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1551)
        at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1493)
        at com.example.assessment.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:113)
...
```

I will mark line 113 in the code below.

I expect the solution to be something simple that I overlooked.

There is one area that I think may be the cause of the problem, but I am not entirely sure what the methods do.  I will mark those areas with a ton of asterisks.

As I said, I tried looking into solutions, but as far as I am aware, everything is correct.

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.assessment;
//Imports are here

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private Camera camera;
    private CameraPreview preview;

    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

    //Skipped this code, it just declared buttons

    PictureCallback picture = new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if (pictureFile == null){
                   //Put error message here
                return;
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d("Assessment", "File not Found");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("Assessment", "Cannot access file");
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //These two lines hides the notification bar at the top of the screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Skipped code here, it just sets up the buttons

        //The following takes the user to a new activity if they lack permissions - I check for permissions for the camera, read externally, and write externally. Yes, I made sure they were all enabled when testing the app.
        if (!(PermissionsActivity.hasAllPermissions())) {
            Intent goToPermissionsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PermissionsActivity.class);
            startActivity(goToPermissionsIntent);
        }

        if(hasCamera(this)){
            camera = getCameraInstance();
            preview = new CameraPreview(this, camera);
            FrameLayout fl_preview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.flo_cameraPreview);
            fl_preview.addView(preview);
        }
    }

    /// Check if this device has a camera - from API
    private boolean hasCamera(Context context) {
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Gets an instance of the Camera object - from API
    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            //Do something here
        }
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_capture:
                //captures photo
//The line below is line 113
                camera.takePicture(null, null, picture);
                break;
            //I had two other switch cases here but they are irreverent for now - they just took you to other activities.
        }
    }

    //I took this from the API, it is never called though
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Assessment");

//******* Below is where the log notification above is referenced.  I am not sure what to do.
        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("Assessment", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        return mediaFile;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (camera != null){
            camera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
            camera = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Working with camera API is really painful, you can use this library. https://github.com/RedApparat/Fotoapparat. this can easy your work so you can focus on other modules of the app.

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Please use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: @Zoe My apologies. I misunderstood the purpose.